# Oracle: spool data to different files depending on where condition (loop)

Tags: oracle, plsql, export, sqlplus

I am trying to get my way around something like this

```
declare
  filename varchar2(100);
begin
  for condition in (select fieldN from mytable) loop
    filename := 'data_for_value'||condition.fieldN||'txt';
    spool filename
    select some_data from some_table where fieldN = condition.fieldN;
    spool off
  end loop;
end;
```

In order to export different sections of data from a table onto different files but I just cannot get it right, I have read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30719272/5664429) and tried to do something similar in consequence:

```
set serveroutput on
set pagesize 0
set numwidth 2
set trimspool on

DECLARE
  filename varchar2(100);
BEGIN
  for field2 in (select field2 from blau2) loop
    filename := 'COST_TRAN_BASE '||field2.field2||'.txt';

    spool "run_query.sql" REPLACE

    select distinct 'spool "' || filename || '.txt"' || chr(10) ||
              'select field1, field3 from blau2 where field2 = ' || field2.field2|| ';' || chr(10) ||
              'spool off' cmd
    from blau2;
    spool off
    @"run_query.sql"
  end loop;
END;
```

But to no avail. I get the feeling that I am not allowed to use the `spool` command where I am trying to (I recently started working in the Oracle environment and the line between SQL*Plus and PL/SQL is still a bit blurry (you can kill me now for my ignorance :') ))

Am I just struggling against the impossible? D:

**Edit:**

with the initial help of Balazs Papp and my follow up investigations I came up with this system:
Using this file:

```
basic_script.txt
-----------------
SET PAGESIZE 0
SET TRIMSPOOL ON

spool RUN_QUERY.sql REPLACE

select distinct 'set heading off' || chr(10) ||
        'spool "BLAU2 ' || field2 || '.txt"' || chr(10) ||
                'select field1||chr(9)|| field3 from blau2 where field2 = ' || 
field2 || ';' || chr(10) ||
                'spool off'
    from blau2;

spool off
-----------
```

And this other file:

```
basic_script_condition.sql:
-----------
set feedback off
set trimspool on
set recsep off
set serveroutput on

col some_column new_value script_name
select decode((select count(*) from (select distinct FIELD2 from BLAU2)),1,'exit.sql','RUN_QUERY.sql') some_column from dual;
@&script_name
-----------
```

Calling them from command line in a simple .bat program:

```
basic_launcher.bat:
-------------
echo exit | sqlplus lmartin/lmartin @"BASIC_SCRIPT.txt"
echo exit | sqlplus lmartin/lmartin @"BASIC_SCRIPT_CONDITION.sql"
-------------
```

A script for exporting the different sections of data in the `BLAU2` table is generated and executed only if there is data to export (if there is no data to export, basic_script would generate a .sql file with `no rows selected` as its content, possibly repeated N times, and the execution would fail, hence the `basic_script_condition.sql` controlling this behavior).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SQL> create table t1 (c1) as select mod(rownum, 4) from dual connect by level <= 12;
```

Just to have some sample data.

```
$ cat run.sql
set heading off feedback off echo off termout off pagesize 0
spool select.sql
select distinct 'spool c1_' || c1 || '.txt ' || chr(10)|| 'select c1 from t1 where c1 = ' || c1 || ';' || chr(10) || 'spool off' from t1 order by 1;
spool off
@select.sql
!rm select.sql
exit

$ sqlplus -s bp/bp @run.sql
```

And the result:

```
$ grep "" *txt
c1_0.txt:         0
c1_0.txt:         0
c1_0.txt:         0
c1_1.txt:         1
c1_1.txt:         1
c1_1.txt:         1
c1_2.txt:         2
c1_2.txt:         2
c1_2.txt:         2
c1_3.txt:         3
c1_3.txt:         3
c1_3.txt:         3
```

Answer (score 1):

`spool` is a SQL*Plus internal command. In your example you are trying to use spool inside a PL/SQL block. The spool command is unknown to the PL/SQL language.

The best option to achieve what you want (write to different text files inside PL/SQL) is to use the UTL_FILE (Oracle 9i and beyond) Oracle internal package.

http://oracle-base.com/articles/9i/utl_file-random-access-of-files-9i

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, I had my suspicions about that hehe. I knew of UTL_FILE but since it requieres special privileges I was reluctant to use it